# i run my contract when use the function send in injected web3,VM Exception while processing transaction: out of gas

Tags: ethereum, solidity

when I try to send eth from contract balance to use account in "injected web3",it show the error ,but javascript vm well done,why?

```
    /**
 * @author: xiao.chen
 * @date: 2018.11.24
 * @description: 基于以太坊ERC20发行代币合约
 */
pragma solidity ^0.4.22;
contract MyToken{
    function transETH() public{
        require(address(this).balance>0);
        address unit = 0x17A29b4981AE8550b7F14a9EB538A42AF5494334;
        unit.transfer(address(this).balance);
    }

    function getETH() public view returns(uint256){
        return address(this).balance;
    }
    function buy() payable {
        //require (isFunding);
        require (msg.value > 0);
    }
}
```

ALERT: [ethjs-rpc] rpc error with payload {"id":833979018102,"jsonrpc":"2.0","params":["0xf86905843b9aca0082746d94c9614e67d02c00d487cb2b3781262b0652f838638084a9d76588822d46a0f102044db47b2df3646ccbf9a36b67b04a27fca6123788bdc99faf9c0792e7a4a00f06491913073755576f07e8256b4ed29b17f013f560599971a59b3e4e5055b8"],"method":"eth_sendRawTransaction"} Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: out of gas

Comment: The error message says `out of gas`. Does the account have any ether?

Answer (score 0):

i do like this:

```
App.contracts.MyToken.deployed().then(function(instance) {
                adoptionInstance = instance;
                return adoptionInstance.transETH();
            }).then(function(result) {
                console.log(result);
            }).catch(function(err) {
                console.log(err.message);
            });
```

only well done;